# My app is not using added dependencies at Run-Time

Tags: java, android

I am using HTTP core and Client jars in my android app.I am running on SDK 23.
I am not getting any compile time error.The app runs until getRally method is called which uses the external dependencies.

My mainactivity.java

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import com.rallydev.rest.RallyRestApi;
import com.rallydev.rest.request.QueryRequest;
import com.rallydev.rest.response.QueryResponse;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    String host = "https://rally1.rallydev.com";


    String applicationName = "Android-Rally";
    RallyRestApi restApi;
    Button buttonlogin;
    EditText etemail,etpass;
    QueryRequest qtestset;
    QueryResponse response;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        etemail=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etemail);
        etpass=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etpassword);
        buttonlogin=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnlogin);
        buttonlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if(etemail.equals("") && etpass.equals(""))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Enter your Rally Credentials",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        getRally();
                    }
                    catch (URISyntaxException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    qtestset = new QueryRequest("Defects");
                    qtestset.setLimit(1);
                    try
                    {
                        response = restApi.query(qtestset);
                        if(!response.wasSuccessful())
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Login Un-Successful",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                        }
                        else{
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Login Successful",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }



                }


            }
        });

    }

    public RallyRestApi getRally() throws URISyntaxException {
        String password = etemail.getText().toString();
        String email=etpass.getText().toString();
        restApi = new RallyRestApi(new URI(host), email,password);
        restApi.setApplicationName(applicationName);
        return restApi;
    }
}
```

My app Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    packagingOptions
            {
                exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
                exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
                exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
            }


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.apetkar.rally_rest_android"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies
        {
            compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
            testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
            compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0')
            compile files('libs/gson-2.2.4.jar')
            compile files('libs/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar')
            compile files('libs/httpcore-4.2.4.jar')
            compile files('libs/httpclient-4.2.5.jar')
            compile files('libs/rally-rest-api-2.2.1.jar')

        }
```

Error Log

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method extractHost(Ljava/net/URI;)Lorg/apache/http/HttpHost; in class Lorg/apache/http/client/utils/URIUtils; or its super classes (declaration of 'org.apache.http.client.utils.URIUtils' appears in /system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar)
                                                                                            at org.apache.http.impl.client.DecompressingHttpClient.getHttpHost(DecompressingHttpClient.java:113)
                                                                                            at org.apache.http.impl.client.DecompressingHttpClient.execute(DecompressingHttpClient.java:108)
                                                                                            at com.rallydev.rest.client.HttpClient.executeRequest(HttpClient.java:157)
                                                                                            at com.rallydev.rest.client.HttpClient.doRequest(HttpClient.java:145)
                                                                                            at com.rallydev.rest.client.BasicAuthClient.doRequest(BasicAuthClient.java:56)
                                                                                            at com.rallydev.rest.client.HttpClient.doGet(HttpClient.java:221)
                                                                                            at com.rallydev.rest.RallyRestApi.query(RallyRestApi.java:172)
                                                                                            at com.example.apetkar.rally_rest_android.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:67)
                                                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
```

I did looked into this issue.The problem is the default `org.apache.http.client.utils.URIUtils` of android is called at runtime which does not contain the method extract host.The method extracthost is in the HttpClient.jar ..So how can I force the app to call the class in the Jar and not the default androids class?

Comment: 1) Try not using JAR files, and `compile` gradle dependencies instead. 2) Do you understand what `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs'` does? If so, you'd realize you don't need to explicitly compile each separate JAR

Comment: Yeah..I have right clicked the jar and selected add in library..then the compilefiles(.jar) is being added.What do you suggest I do here??I'll remove the jars and add compile gradle dependencies and get back

Answer (score 1):

You're using an old Apache HTTP client... And one that isn't made for Android

```
compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient-android', version: '4.3.5.1'
```

Simliarly, you really don't need JAR files, I don't think.

```
compile group: 'com.rallydev.rest', name: 'rally-rest-api', version: '2.2.1'
compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.0'
compile group: 'commons-logging', name: 'commons-logging', version: '1.2'
```

> how can I force the app to call the class in the Jar and not the default androids class

I'm not sure if that Rally API library requires Apache HTTP, but I would suggest a different HTTP library since Apache HTTP was removed in Android 23, which is what you've compiled against, so the code shouldn't be calling the default class.

Comment: I changed the rallyrestapi dependencies locally to httpclient-android.The java-rallyrestapi is built on http-client and httpcore which I had imported earlier..Thanks for your help anyways

Comment: Also I fear it will not allow running network operations on the main thread..any way arround that??

Comment: I don't think HTTPClient runs on the main thread. But the Volley or OkHTTP libraries are good alternatives